# creating function to add word into dictionary

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to create function that adds words into dictionary

so far i made this

```
void addWord(char **dictionary,int *dictionarySize,int *wordsInDictionary,char *word){
if(dictionary == NULL)
{
    *dictionary = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(*dictionarySize));
}
else
{
    if(*wordsInDictionary==*dictionarySize)
    {
        *dictionary = (char *)realloc(dictionary,sizeof(char*)*(*dictionarySize)*2);
        (*dictionarySize)*=2;
    }
}
dictionary[*wordsInDictionary]=word;
(*wordsInDictionary)++;
```

}

in main() i have

```
int i;
int dictSize = 1;
int wordsInDict = 0;
char *word;
char *dictionary;
dictionary=NULL;
```

then i want to print all words in dictionary , but here i get warning that %s is expecting char* but it is int

```
printf("Stats: dictsize: %d, words in dict: %d\n", dictSize,wordsInDict);
    for(i=0;i<wordsInDict;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n",i, dictionary[i]);
    }
```

it also gives me errors when i try to add words

i use this call to add words

```
addWord(&dictionary,&dictSize,&wordsInDict,word);
```

Comment: `char *dictionary;` then `dictionary[i]` is `char`.

Comment: [Do **NOT** cast the return value of `malloc()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Answer (score 1):

In your `addWord` function, `dictionary` will *never* be `NULL`.

And that's only the start of your problems. Because you want dictionary to be an array of arrays, which mean you need to declare it as a pointer to a pointer (if you want it to be dynamic). However, you declare it as just a (single) pointer. It's in the `main` function (or where ever you declare it originally) that you need to declare it as a pointer to a pointer. ***And*** you need to initialize it, or it will have an indeterminate value and using it in any way other than initializing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That means your `addWord` function should take a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, i.e. one more level of indirection. And you need to use the dereference operator to get the original pointer to pointer.

So the `addWord` function should start like e.g.

```
void addWord(char ***dictionary, int *dictionarySize, int *wordsInDictionary,char *word){
    if(*dictionary == NULL)
    {
        *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (*dictionarySize));
    }
    ...
}
```

Also note that I [don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Also note that `realloc` *can* fail, and then will return `NULL`, so if you assign the return to the same pointer you reallocate you will loose the original pointer. Always use a temporary pointer for the return-value of `realloc` and only assign to the real pointer after checking that the reallocation succeeded.

Comment: what do you mean i want array of arrays? i want array of strings, do you view string as an array of characters? i know this im just not used to it, is there any better approach on this? for example without using ***dictionary which looks complicated to me

Comment: @lllook And what is a string? It is, basically, an *array* of characters. And if you want an array of strings, you want an array of arrays, and if you want to allocate those dynamically, then you need a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @lllook Also be careful with how you use `word`, if you reuse it to read multiple words then all entries will be equal to the last word because all entries use the same pointer. You might want to use e.g. `strdup` to duplicate the strings (but if you do then you have to remember to free the actual strings as well).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you put together the members of the `dictionary` in one as a structure, rather than having individually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dictionary {
    char **words;//array of char *
    int size;
    int numOfWords;
} Dictionary;

Dictionary *D_new(void){
    Dictionary *dic = malloc(sizeof(*dic));
    if(dic){
        dic->size = 16;//initial size
        dic->words = malloc(dic->size * sizeof(*dic->words));//check omitted
        dic->numOfWords = 0;
    }
    return dic;
}
void D_drop(Dictionary *dic){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<dic->numOfWords; ++i)
        free(dic->words[i]);
    free(dic->words);
    free(dic);
}
void addWord(Dictionary *dic, const char *word){
    if(dic == NULL){
        return ;
    }
    if(dic->numOfWords == dic->size){
        dic->words = realloc(dic->words, sizeof(*dic->words)*(dic->size*=2));//check omitted
    }
    dic->words[dic->numOfWords++]=strdup(word);//make copy
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    Dictionary *dictionary = D_new();
    addWord(dictionary, "apple");
    addWord(dictionary, "banana");
    addWord(dictionary, "melon");

    printf("Stats: dictsize: %d, words in dict: %d\n", 
    dictionary->size, dictionary->numOfWords);
    for(i=0;i<dictionary->numOfWords;i++){
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, dictionary->words[i]);
    }

    D_drop(dictionary);
    return 0;
}
```